# Limit of t-score as r->0 (for Pearson's correlation)

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, p-value, pearson-r

I have a very basic question. The t-score used in the significance test for the Pearson's correlation is given by:
$$
t = r \frac{\sqrt{(n-2)}}{\sqrt{(1-r^2)}},
$$
where $n$ is the sample size and $r$ is the correlation.
Does this mean it is impossible to detect a statistically significant zero correlation ($r=0$) as in that case $t \rightarrow 0$? Or am I misinterpreting the above equation?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by a “statistically significant correlation ($r=0$)?

Comment: I meant to say that if we decide on some threshold (p=0.05) for the significant test, we would compute the t-score and find the corresponding p-value to see if it exceeds 0.05 or not. As $t$ becomes larger, the likelihood of passing the test increases. As $t \rightarrow 0$, the likelihood of passing the text should also decrease (am thinking in terms of the area under the curve). Does this make more sense?

Comment: 1) As $t$ approaches zero, why shouldn’t the likelihood of passing the test decrease? // 2) Why do you think that large a $t$ means a high p-value?

Comment: I guess I am agreeing with you. As $t \rightarrow 0$, I think the likelihood of passing the text should decrease (analogous to small z-score values). And conversely, a large $t$ means it is likelier the null is rejected, again similar to how we would interpret a large z-score.

Comment: Then what’s the issue?

Comment: My confusion is arising for the case $r=0$. In that case, $t=0$. Is $t=0$ not going to fail the significance test regardless of what significance level we choose? For any chosen significance level $\alpha$, we want $t > t_{crit}$ for the test to pass, where $t_{crit}$ is the critical value corresponding to $\alpha$. But $t > t_{crit}$ is never going to be satisfied if $t=0$.

Comment: @fivethirds assuming your null hypothesis is $r=0$ (there is no correlation) and your alternate hypothesis is $r \neq 0$ for the significance test, is there any reason you want to "pass" the significance test (more specifically, reject the null hypothesis) when the test statistic suggest $r$ is effectively zero? Not "passing" the test simply means there is no evidence for us to believe otherwise than what we already assumed ($r=0$).

Comment: If $t=0$. either we observed the $r=0$ proposed by the null hypothesis, or we have a sample size of $2$, but then we’re always going to get an empirical correlation of $r=1$ or an undefined $r$.

Comment: Dave and B. Liu: Thanks for your responses. I see that I was confusing myself unnecessarily. Normally we are looking for an "effect" (e.g., drug effects) that would be confirmed by rejecting the null. In my application, it so happens that the theory makes a prediction of zero correlation, which happens to be the null result. So if I am unable to reject the null (because $t=0$) that is indeed confirming the theory. I now realize all this sounds self-evident! Please feel free to delete this entire thread as it is not adding much to the discourse :)

Comment: On the contrary, I think it would be great if you posted a self-answer explaining what you've learned.

Comment: The question seems to me to potentially be conflating $\rho\to 0$ with $r\to 0$. A small $|t|$-value doesn't have a low probability to reject, it's absolutely guaranteed not to reject. Low probability occurs when $\rho$ is small (because $|t|$ might still sometimes be large enough to be in the rejection region).

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out my confusion. As I indicated in the comment thread, the source of my confusion was that in my particular application a physical theory makes a prediction that the two variables I was analyzing have a zero correlation. This happens to be the null result. I was finding that for very low $r$, the p-value was not small enough to reject the null. But that just means the calculated $r$ is too small to be indistinguishable from zero (for the chosen confidence level), which in effect means the data is not inconsistent with the prediction by the theory.

Comment: Your last sentence contains a common mistake. A high p-value does not confirm the null hypothesis. It means that the data you have collected are not inconsistent with the null hypothesis. This does not preclude the data being *more* consistent with a different value, however. (In many cases (the technical term is *maximum likelihood estimation*), there is an argument that the most likely value is the estimated value, not the value under the unrejected null hypothesis.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: "that the most likely value is the estimated value, not the value under the unrejected null hypothesis".


Does this point become less of an issue if the estimated value is not too different from the value under the unrejected null hypothesis? That is what is happening in my case. The values of $r$ for which I am unable to reject the null hypothesis ($r=0$) are pretty small to begin with ($r \sim 0.05$).

Comment: What is your tolerance for "close enough to zero" or "basically zero"? // You might be interested in equivalence testing.

Comment: "What is your tolerance for "close enough to zero" or "basically zero"?" I was trying to ground this in the significance test itself. Inability to reject the null means my estimated value of $r$ (say, 0.05) is "basically zero." It it weren't, then I would have been able to reject the null. At least, that was my thinking. [Edit: I will also look up equivalence testing. Thanks.]